# Invalid option passed to GNU make though Bash array

Tags: arrays, bash, gnu-make

I'm trying to tune a bash test script that automatically builds a package. The relevant portion of the script is:

```bash
# https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/cryptopp/5.6.3/8.fc27/data/logs/i686/build.log
# https://kojipkgs.fedoraproject.org//packages/cryptopp/5.6.3/8.fc27/data/logs/x86_64/build.log
if [[ ("$IS_X86" -ne "0") ]]; then
    MARCH_OPT=(-m32 -march=i686)
else
    MARCH_OPT=(-m64 -mtune=generic)
fi

FEDORA_FLAGS=(-DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Werror=format-security -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2
    -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4
    -specs=/usr/lib/rpm/redhat/redhat-hardened-cc1 "${MARCH_OPT[@]}" -fasynchronous-unwind-tables)

"$MAKE" distclean > /dev/null 2>&1

CXX="g++" "$MAKE" "${MAKEARGS[@]}" CXXFLAGS="${FEDORA_FLAGS[@]}" cryptest.exe 2>&1
```

Its producing an error:

```
Testing: Fedora standard build

make: invalid option -- 'g'
make: unrecognized option '--param=ssp-buffer-size=4'
make: invalid option -- 'c'
make: invalid option -- '='
make: invalid option -- '/'
make: invalid option -- 'u'
make: invalid option -- '/'
make: invalid option -- '6'
make: invalid option -- '4'
make: invalid option -- 'u'
make: invalid option -- '='
make: invalid option -- 'g'
make: invalid option -- 'c'
Usage: make [options] [target] ...
Options:
  -b, -m                      Ignored for compatibility.
  -B, --always-make           Unconditionally make all targets.
  -C DIRECTORY, --directory=DIRECTORY
                              Change to DIRECTORY before doing anything.
  -d                          Print lots of debugging information.
  --debug[=FLAGS]             Print various types of debugging information.
  -e, --environment-overrides
                              Environment variables override makefiles.
...
```

I think the problem has something to do with the Bash array. But I'm pretty sure things are correct with respect to it. The elements are enclosed in parenthesis; and its elements are referenced with `${VAR[@]}`. I also tried quoting each value in the `FEDORA_FLAGS` array, but it produced the same error.

What is producing the error, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CXXFLAGS="${FEDORA_FLAGS[@]}"` should be `CXXFLAGS="${FEDORA_FLAGS[*]}"`; the behavior of a `@`-indexed array when quoted means only the first element of the array is being treated as part of the word starting with `CXXFLAGS`; the rest of the elements are treated as arguments to `$MAKE` itself. You are getting

```
CXX="g++" "$MAKE" "${MAKEARGS[@]}" CXXFLAGS=-DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -O2 -g ...
```

instead of

```
CXX="g++" "$MAKE" "${MAKEARGS[@]}" "CXXFLAGS=-DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -O2 -g ..."
```

Comment: Thanks Chepner. The `"${FEDORA_FLAGS[*]}"` fixed it. This is the sort of thing that takes the fun out of Bash scripting. If they tell us to do something (like use `"${VAR[@]}"` syntax), then it should work everywhere without the need to remember special rules. In my case, I did not even know about the rule...

Comment: The problem is that the `CXXFLAGS` parameter is exactly the kind of thing that doesn't work for arbitrary parameters. Using an array here actually doesn't help you, because ultimately you are just flattening the array to a single string to pass as the value of a regular variable; you aren't passing the elements of the array as separate words. You would get the *exact* same results with `FEDORA_FLAGS="-DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. ..."` and `CXXFLAGS="$FEDORA_FLAGS"`.

Comment: Put another way: passing arguments to the compiler using a single variable `CXXFLAGS` means you can't pass arguments that contain whitespace.